# Aborting blocking thread

Tags: .net, multithreading

I have a thread that is blocking on a Networkstream `Read` call. How do I best abort this thread? I tried calling `Thread.Abort` on the thread from another thread, which according to MSDN should raise a `ThreadAbortException`. However the `ThreadAbortException` is not raised at all in the thread. It is however, when I remove the blocking `Read` call and just have the thread sit in a loop. What is the best way to do this? Can I wait on the `Read` call and an event at the same time so the thread unblocks if either occurs? Then I could just signal that event from another thread.

Comment: Hello, have you try to modify buffer size in order not to be blocking.Using a loop on your thread and a buffer size allow you to stop your thread when you want ;-)

Comment: How about not blocking in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Thread.Abort` only aborts when the thread is running managed code, but your thread is waiting on the unmanaged socket, so nothing happens until the socket unblocks.

Closing the socket is the best option here.

Answer (score 3):

Close the socket!  The Read should then throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Set

```
stream.ReadTimeout = timeout; 
// timeout in ms
```

before using

```
stream.Read(....
```

This will force the read to timeout and allows to do something when nothing gets read for the specified *timeout* in milliseconds. See [Stream::ReadTimeout Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.readtimeout.aspx) or [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/1ab61b3a-823c-4785-b130-d5d253f11d4d) on MSDN.
This way you can implement a read which only blocks for the specified *timeout*. Use other synchronization methods to determine whether the reading should continue or the thread should finish. The timeout will throw an exception.